# android print from pdfview

Tags: android, pdfview, androidpdfviewer

I have an app is working with PDFView. Today I added buttons for print by send data to printer directly. Do you have any solution, how to print data from PDFView just click on button. Note: Below image have 2 buttons but my purpose need only one button calls "Print Food" and other button will other purpose. Thanks & Best Regards.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs you can find tutorial here

Comment: also look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975339/generate-pdf-from-android-using-printedpdfdocument-and-view-draw

Comment: Dear Learning Always, I tried 2 days in search. Now solution solved. I just download app from Play Store name: Printer+ so that app will automatic print our app from the PDFView. Thank You for your replied and Thanks for Printer+ App.

Answer (score 0):

I tried 2 days in search. Now solution solved. I just download app from Play Store name: Printer+ so that app will automatic print our app from the PDFView. Thank You for your replied and Thanks for Printer+ App.

[image]